# Django template {% if x.number == 0 %} does not work

Tags: django

This `{% if x.number == 1 %}` and `{% if x.number == 2 %}` work good

but `{% if x.number == 0 %}` does not work. Why?

```
  {% for d in data %}
    {% for x in d.animalnumber_set.all %}

        {{ x.number }} <!-- Nothing displays. ->
        {% if x.number == 1 %}
            <p>Something</p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if x.number == 2 %}
            <p>Something 2</p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if x.number == 0 %}
            <p>Nothing</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

In database `number` filed is `choices`. How to replace `{% if x.number == 0 %}`? `== None` also does not work.

```
----
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I don't see a `0` in the list of choices so I am not sure why you expect it to work?

Comment: and what is the value in database if you select the `----`?

Comment: Can you dump {{ x.number }} in your template and check that it is indeed `0`, and not `None` or something else?

Comment: @SteveMayne `{{ x.number }}` nothing displays. I think that because it is in `{% for x in d.animalnumber_set.all %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the avaialble choices are between 1-6, why do you check for x.number == 0? This will never occur.

If the user doesn't have any animalnumber the d.animalnumber_set.all will return None. So the control would be to check if x is empty

```
{% for d in data %}
    {% for x in d.animalnumber_set.all %}

        {% if x.number == 1 %}
            <p>Something</p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if x.number == 2 %}
            <p>Something 2</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
        <p>Nothing</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

if the data has no value or 0, use `not`

```
{% if not x.number %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `{% if x.number == 0 %}` to `{% if not x.number %}` and still this `if` not working

Comment: Are you sure x.number has no value? or maybe it is not none, it just `blank " "`?

Comment: I think that my object does not exist `{% for x in d.animalnumber_set.all %}` http://dpaste.com/hold/1021595/ but I don't know how to change it

Comment: where is your NUMBER_CHOICES? I need to clarify something

Comment: `NUMBER_CHOICES = zip( range(1,6), range(1,6) )`

Comment: based on the choices there is no 0. Why you need this `{% if x.number == 0 %}`?

Comment: If the user has not set a `number` value I need display other data